Linear and bilinear forms in Ritz method
I'm trying to understand an article about Calculus of Variations applied to Solid Mechanics (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325945710_APPLICATION_OF_VARIATIONAL_METHODS_AND_GALERKIN_METHOD_IN_SOLVING_ENGINEERING_PROBLEMS_REPRESENTED_BY_ORDINARY_DIFFERENTIAL_EQUATIONS_1). They solve the equation $$-\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} - u + x^2 = 0 \ , \ 0<x<1 \ ; \ u(0)=u(1)=0$$
So, they assume a set of trial functions $w$, apply integration by parts to the functional $ \int_0^1 w*\left[-\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} - u + x^2\right]\,dx$ and equal it to $0$. This results in $$\left[-w*\frac{du}{dx}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{dw}{dx}*\frac{du}{dx} \,dx - \int_0^1w*u\,dx+\int_0^1w*x^2\,dx = 0$$.
The part that I don't understand is why they say that this last expression can be expressed as bilinear and linear forms where $B^e(w,u) = L^e(w)$, and the bilinear form is $B(w,u) = \int_0^1 \frac{dw}{dx}*\frac{du}{dx}\,dx$, and the linear form is $L(w) = -\int_0^1x^2*w \,dx + \left[w*\frac{du}{dx}\right]_0^1$
I know that in Ritz method, the objective is to minimize $\int\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{2}\left(\Delta w\right)^2 -fw \,dx\,dy$. I also know that this is a quadratic functional, but there must be something I'm not getting into.
